# Using Geocoder Rails with Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq, rails-geocoder

Im wanting sidekiq to handle my background process for `geocoder`

Ive never really used sidekiq so needless to say ive run into some trouble.  I keep getting an `undefined method geocoded_by` error.  My code is below.

#### assets/workers/geocode_worker

```
class GeocodeWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    extend ::Geocoder::Model::ActiveRecord

    def perform
        geocoded_by :address
        reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude do |obj,results|
          if geo = results.first
            obj.city    = geo.city
            obj.zipcode = geo.postal_code

         end
        end
    after_validation :geocode, :reverse_geocode


        def self.import(file)
            CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
                Location.create! row.to_hash
        end
    end
end
end
```

#### Location model

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    GeocodeWorker.perform_async
end
```

Answer (score 1):

the geocoder stuff goes into the model class:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base 
   geocoded_by :address
   after_validation :geocode, :reverse_geocode
   reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude do |obj,results|
      if geo = results.first
         obj.city    = geo.city
         obj.zipcode = geo.postal_code
      end
   end

   def self.import(file)
       CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
         Location.create! row.to_hash
       end
    end
end
```

Then I assume the task of your worker is to import a file:

```
class ImportLocationWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

    def perform(file_path)
        Location.import(file_path)
    end
end
```

To start a worker to import a file, call:

```
ImportLocationWorker.perform_async("/some/path/to/file.csv")
```

Comment: do i call it from the console?

Comment: you can call it from the rails console, or from any controller/model in your application.

Comment: One hint: workers should be named "actively", as a verb: `ImportLocationsWorker`.  Your models are nouns.  Your workers are verbs.